# popened process never dies

Tags: php, apache2, popen

I am using this neat code that tails a logfile live on the browser (thanks SO!)
The problem is that tail remains running even after user closes the tab/browser/pc

any ideas?

logs are still being written while window is closed, so I know that the server is trying to send something and fails, but the if connection_status()​!=0 seems to never fire

```
<?php
$files = scandir('somefile', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newestfile = $files[0];
echo "$newestfile<br/>\n";
$handle = popen("tail -fn +1 ./somedir/" . $newestfile . " 2>&1", 'r');
while(!feof($handle)) {
    if (connection_status()​!=0){
    exec("killall tail");
    pclose($handle);
    }
    $buffer = fgets($handle);
    echo "$buffer<br/>\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
pclose($handle);
?>
```

Update:

I ended up using a modified version of this:
https://github.com/richardvk/web_file_tail

KUDOS to this guy!

Comment: The PHP process can't know when the browser closes and you have an infinite loop. I would suggest to change your logic and create a loop in JS that calls the PHP script via Ajax. The PHP in this case would only read the last few lines since the last read, without any loop. As soon as the browser is closed, the Ajax calls will stop so your server won't be stuck.

Comment: Hello, I like this process but the problem is that when the window is opened, I want all the log from line 1 and then append any new lines as they happen, I find this difficult to implement though

Comment: It's just a logic problem, you can keep track of the last line of the log you read. When the browser open it's 0 so the PHP gets all the lines, then the second time it loops the php only gets the lines that it didn't already provide. You can make the setinterval 1 second on JS so it's very quick to retrieve as soon as they happen

Comment: I'll try and give it a go, but I might need a bit of help :) I'll be back!